# How can I easily test if XML file is well-formed in Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, validation

I know there are quite some threads talking about validating XML file against its XML schema, such as : [validate-xml-using-libxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646689/validate-xml-using-libxml) and [xml-schema-validation-with-relaxng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258462/xml-schema-validation-with-relaxng)

So if there is a simple Perl module on CPAN that can test this with minimal code, then that would be very fantastic to know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Perl module that validates an XML against a schema?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322080/is-there-a-perl-module-that-validates-an-xml-against-a-schema)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use [XML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Parser).

Note that your question title refers to being well-formatted (well-formed?) whereas the body refers to validation. If you want to validate (against a schema) check out [XML::Validator::Schema](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Validator-Schema).

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer and sorry about the wrong term, yeah, you are right, I mean well-formed not well-formatted :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [Test::XML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-XML). It gives you methods `is_xml`, `is_well_formed_xml`.

Comment: Test::XML is for writing test scripts ala Test::More and Test::Builder, and as such isn't very useful outside of a test script.  But you can examine its source code to see how to use XML::Parser to check if your XML is well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

There's [XML::Compile](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Compile), but it's not easy until you learn to use the module.

Answer (score 0):

Since [XML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Parser) will die if a parsing error occurs, try this for minimal code:

`XML::Parser->new->parse($xml);`